# Unable to access location in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, 22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop on my ASUS K55VJ laptop. I Have two drives in the laptop: the OS is installed on a 250 GB SSD and the secondary drive is a 750 GB WD Scorpion HDD where I keep my files.

There is no other partition on the SSD, but I have three partitions on the HDD, two of which can be mounted. However, when I want to mount `/dev/sdb3`, it says that it can't access the location or is unable to mount `Movies` in `dev/sdb3`. It was accessible earlier though. I'm attaching the error I get while trying to access the partition of my HDD.

[image: Unable to access location error]

I tried running `sudo ntfsfix`, which worked for a single time, but now it is not working. Do suggest me a viable and easy option to fix this.

Comment: IF this is an ntfs partition, attach that partition to MS and have it checked there. Only MS Windows can fully check and repair its proprietary file system format

Comment: then i have to install windows on the ssd ??

Comment: *then i have to install windows on the ssd ??* No, but again, if the file system on the problematic partition(s) is NTFS and it becomes corrupt for whatever reason then you can ONLY correct it, if still possible, in Windows and using Windows tools. If you AREN'T dual-booting with Windows then you shouldn't keep NTFS partitions around.

Comment: You Should try to Create a Windows PE like Hiren's Boot CD etc . it does not requires you to install windows in your pc it needs a usb to the iso to be flashed